# Get URL of each video in SharePoint 2013 library with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-jsom

I need to get the URL of each video in a library with JavaScript (I don't know how many videos will be in the library). I also need to get specific information about each video, such as date created. How would I do this? I am using a Script Editor web part to execute the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rest API to get the information you wanted.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('library title')/files
```

[image]

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/dev/Doc')/Files
```

[image]
[Get to know the SharePoint REST service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom)

Answer (score 0):

Rest call with the below url will get you what you looking for

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + youlistname + "')/items?$select=*,FileRef/FileRef"
```